# How to call a C function which returns a pointer to struct in Java?

Tags: java, c

I have a C function:

```
AES_KEY* generate_aes128_key()
```

which generates a AES_KEY*. struct AES_KEY is defined in openssl, and is allocated memory in the body of the function. I want to call this function in Java to get a AES_KEY, so how can I do it?

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier (and quite possibly faster at run-time as well) to use [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/bouncy-castle.html).

Comment: If you want to call native functions from Java then you're looking at using JNI or maybe JNA.  A native pointer can *probably* be returned as a Java `long` (where "probably" accounts for the fact that native pointer sizes are implementation-dependant). That may not be quite what you want, however, because Java has no direct way of using the pointer-converted-to-`long`; you would need one or more additional native methods.

Comment: The [list of standard security names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) seems to suggest that this can be done with the java.security.\* and javax.crypto.\* classes.  In particular, it says KeyGenerator must support AES 128-bit.

Comment: JNA will likely be the easiest approach. There's also SWIG, which can automatically generate Java bindings for C structs and C++ classes -- but that would cost you some time to set up.